# C - How to read a string with unknown length

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int i=0;
    int size=1;
    char *pntName=NULL;//a pointer to an array of chars.
    pntName = (char*) malloc(size *sizeof(char));//allocate sapce for the first char. 
    while(pntName[size-1]!=':'){
        if(pntName!=NULL)//check the case couldn't allocate 
           printf("Error");
        else{
            if(i<size){//meaning there is space for new char.
                scanf("%c",&pntName[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else{//case we don't have enough space 
                size++;
                pntName = (char*)realloc(pntName,(size)*sizeof(char));//reallocat space.
                scanf("%c",&pntName[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
     }
        return 1;
}
```

i'm trying to read a string which contain a name. The user can input characters until he inputs ':'.
what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which problem do you face?

Comment: you shouldnt cast the results of malloc in c, also please give us some of the unexpected results youre facing

Comment: And `sizeof(char)` cannot differ from `1`. Using it is nonsense.

Comment: Besides the missing `#include`s the code as shown does not contain any major issue. It however does not loop around the scanning/reallocation part, so it reads just one `char`, then ends.

Comment: Referring your update: `... == ...` are you sure?

Comment: You malloc size bytes, then try to access pntName[size], which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Indexing a C array is 0-based.

Comment: Olef- i didn't understand your answer. i would happy if you explain in detail.

Comment: alk- how do i read it correctly?

Comment: `pntName = (char*) malloc(size *sizeof(char)); while(pntName[size-1]!=':'){` is a problem as `pntName[size-1]` has not been assigned a value yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string needs to be terminated with `'\0'` so allow an extra character. When reallocating it is best to use another pointer in case the reallocation fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    int size=1;
    char *pntName=NULL;//a pointer to an array of chars.
    char *temp=NULL;//a temporary pointer

    pntName = malloc( size + 1);//allocate space for two char one for the '\0' to terminate the string
    while(1){
        size++;
        temp = realloc(pntName, size + 1);//reallocat space.
        if ( temp == NULL) {
            printf ( "error allocating memory");
            free ( pntName);
            return 1;
        }
        pntName = temp;
        if ( ( scanf("%c",&pntName[i])) == 1) {
            i++;
            pntName[i] = '\0'; // terminate the string
            if ( pntName[i-1] == ':') {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf ( "\n%s\n", pntName);
    free ( pntName);// release memory
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error case is problematic here.

```
if (pntName != NULL)
   printf("Error");
```

On the first iteration of the loop before any input has been read, `pntName` is allocated (set to something non-null), so the error condition passes and the string "Error" is printed out.  You are not advancing toward exiting the while condition, so this repeats indefinitely.

Comment: i fixed that, but i stil have problem when i print the string, sometimes it prints other values after the ':'